# Extend globally declared Type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

#### Background:

I'm creating an app that will work with Permissions and Clipboard API. Standard Typescript library doesn't have typings for much of cutting-edge Clipboard API stuff, so I went to create a `.d.ts` file to extend such incomplete interfaces. It contains declarations like that:

```js
declare class ClipboardItem {
  constructor(data: { [mimeType: string]: Blob });
}
```

and I reference it from my code this way: `/// <reference path="clipboard.d.ts" />`

So far so good: absent interfaces are getting added, existing ones get extended, autocompletion is working correctly. But then I came to requesting `"clipboard-read"` permission. I want to pass this string when calling `navigator.permissions.query({name: "clipboard-read"})` where `name`'s type is defined in standard Typescript library as follows:

```js
type PermissionName = "geolocation" |  ... | "clipboard";
```

And it doesn't have "clipboard-read" there. So I want to extend it so that it includes "clipboard-read". Now, if in my `.d.ts` file I write

```
type PermissionName = 'clipboard-read';
```

it shows me an error `Duplicate identifier 'PermissionName'.ts(2300)`. I tried other varieties but all of them came down to Duplicate identifier error.

#### Question:

Is there a way to extend not an `interface`, but a `type` that was already globally declared elsewhere? What should I do to achieve that?

Comment: Can you create a new type which includes that one? `type ExtendedPermissionName = PermissionName | 'clipboard-read'`;

Comment: @dcchuck I can, but the `navigator.permissions.query` function will still expect `PermissionName` as a type of `name` property, leading to the same error: `Type '"clipboard-write"' is not assignable to type 'PermissionName'`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot "override" an existing type with Typescript. You could modify the `lib/dom.d.ts` file in the `node_modules` folder but it's definitely not a good option in my opinion.

The only viable solution I see is to cast:

```
navigator.permissions.query({name: 'clipboard-write' as PermissionName});
```

or to create a custom type and a wrapping method (which will casts):

```
type  MyPermissionName = PermissionName | 'clipboard-read' | 'clipboard-write';

function requestPermission(permission: MyPermissionName) {
  return navigator.permissions.query({name: permission as PermissionName});
}
```