# How to fix the "Cannot find name 'ClipboardItem'" error?

Tags: typescript, blob, navigator, html5-clipboard-api, typescript-lib-dom

Getting the error

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ClipboardItem'

when trying to create a `ClipboardItem` for `navigator.clipboard.write()`.

```
const clipboardItemInput = new ClipboardItem({'image/png' : blobInput});
 await navigator.clipboard.write([clipboardItemInput]);
```

I am using Angular 6. Do I need to add any dependencies, or is there any other method?

Comment: Also I'm getting error Property 'write' does not exist on type 'Clipboard'.

Comment: You can circumvent that by casting navigator.clipBoard to any => (navigator.clipboard as any).write

Answer (score 8):

**For TypeScript 4.4 and higher**

[TypeScript 4.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/) updated the standard definitions library with missing interfaces and methods ([full list of changes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator/issues/1029#issuecomment-869224737)), so everything should work out-of-the-box. The following sample code now compiles without additional interfaces/declaration merges:

```js
declare const image: ClipboardItemData;
(async () => {
  const item = new ClipboardItem({ "image/png": image });

  const files = await navigator.clipboard.read();
  if( files.length ) return;

  await navigator.clipboard.write([item]);
})();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gSwLZQHMQAueAYQmwAcAjJWYASQxFwBEoMoBuAKAAooaAJ4ow8fgEp4AXgB88AN694iVJhwtcs%20ChAB3cpVr0YTLf0XwARHkIgA9FRQFrpO0XgBfSXxVr0LAAzbAgQNB0ofShsLBQoADdsAk4kGAA6SGo6BnS4KGApPlVsIP54ELC0dLCXDAALeGk4DABXGBQ-VSiYuMTk1Iysk1z9GFiQfgBtCdwAXV9eHyKgA)

---

**For TypeScript 4.3 and lower**

As of 2021, the TypeScript standard library is still missing a definition for the Clipboard API (and that is the reason for the "Cannot find name 'ClipboardItem'" error). There is an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43821) on the source repository and a [pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator/pull/1004) on the DOM lib generator repository (because the standard library is autogenerated) that should address the issue.

In the meantime, you can add the following definitions matching how the standard library defines other global interfaces (do not forget to add a triple-slash directive `/// <reference types="../../index" />` at the top of the importing file):

```ts
interface ClipboardItem {
  readonly types: string[];
  readonly presentationStyle: "unspecified" | "inline" | "attachment";
  getType(): Promise<Blob>;
}

interface ClipboardItemData {
  [mimeType: string]: Blob | string | Promise<Blob | string>;
}

declare var ClipboardItem: {
  prototype: ClipboardItem;
  new (itemData: ClipboardItemData): ClipboardItem;
};
```

Note that the `ClipboardItemData` is defined to take either `Blob`, `string`, or a promise that returns one of the former and not just a `Blob` (see the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardItem/ClipboardItem), for example). It also does not hurt to augment the `Clipboard` interface with missing `read` and `write` methods:

```ts
interface Clipboard {
  read(): Promise<DataTransfer>;
  write(data: ClipboardItem[]): Promise<void>;
}
```

Finally, let's test that the definitions work as expected:

```ts
declare const image: Blob;
(async () => {
  const item = new ClipboardItem({ ["image/png"]: image });

  const { files } = await navigator.clipboard.read();
  if( files.length ) return;

  await navigator.clipboard.write([item]);
})();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=30&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIBtgAcBGB7OKAEwElIBbZAbwChlkoI4i8R0BPZMdrCAZwBcyPmCigA5gG0AugG46DJizacsjPhHBwwwVgGVu6CEIBEAVxB9eCYDGAQiJ5AB9kJ0JhAQnrk9rCIABbkmmAm8vTiEGAAKjwQABQAlEIAClB45MAaADwAQuh4OAB88gC%20NDSgkLCIKBjY%20ISkFAAi2nDUCpJZIXG8QiJiIOLSQgVFLsKiElPpmdkQ%20YU4U0MSpTQVNEQQCOiEKABuhGiYuATEZBDkQrT0anhgT-FCDRfN1%20QRyF4A7sgEsA2h03ucmlcQQEUmdGpcWjdyvIquBoPAkLCPsQuvRGMxkmkMllcu0AjEoHBLDBoJt6H8xJAEkRQZiIQjyDIYfNiUsjnhgERNttdvtDsgEKwRMhgOQ4FFxit5Ak4Hx2CAEICksgALzFHHiyVgaUUHW-CAA95sr4JKjISTuWVRAD0WBGJjG0sdKDKSWR9AlliNtrsRj4yDKprgfzgwN%20cCOwHE2jwUAAdPs4c1U3iiMkfrYEsgQ-xU0YRmBAsgtYwwGYoCA-cgozGjSB44nk2mM1iiKn6cDEpIB%20RpL6tkk8zQgA)

Answer (score 3):

The Typescript version might not incorporate all the features. This is where we need to extend it by creating typings or extending the existing ones.
To solve the issue, try to create a **types.d.ts** file ([reference1](https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration#typescript-typings)) and put the following in it:

```
declare class ClipboardItem {
  constructor(data: { [mimeType: string]: Blob });
}
```

Then reference the file in your component code with:

```
/// <reference path="types.d.ts" />
```

Then feel free to use the Class.

```
const item = new ClipboardItem({ "image/png": blob });
window.navigator['clipboard'].write([item]);
```

Inspiration: [reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59968957/extend-globally-declared-type-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

simple but not great

```js
let anyNavigator: any;
anyNavigator = window.navigator;
const clipboardItemInput = new ClipboardItem({'image/png' : blobInput});
await anyNavigator.clipboard.write([clipboardItemInput]);
```

If you want to `read clipboard` or call any function that has a return value:

```js
let anyNavigator: any;
anyNavigator = window.navigator;
(anyNavigator.clipboard.readText() as Promise<string>).then(data => {
// ...
});
```