# How do I add possible values to existing union type declared in standard library in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, interface, extend, typing

Consider this `PermissionName` type declared in `lib.dom.d.ts`:

```
type PermissionName = "geolocation" | "notifications" | // More...
```

Can I somehow add a value to it from my own `app.d.ts` file? For example (code doesn't work):

```
declare global {

    type PermissionName = PermissionName | "local-fonts";

}

export {}
```

so that this code would work (this is the reason why I cannot declare new type, because other APIs is using this type)?

```
await navigator.permissions.query({
    name: "local-fonts"
});
```

---

Current workaround:

```
await navigator.permissions.query({
    name: <any>"local-fonts"
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extend globally declared Type in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59968957/extend-globally-declared-type-in-typescript)

Comment: @TanekLoc hi, I have seen that one before. Yeah it's a duplicate though I am trying to get a newer answer in hope that there is better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to augment is not `PermissionName`, but `navigator.permissions.query`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/FAEwpgxgNghgTmABAcygewEYyog3sRRASwDsAXMOAMxgiQAVKBbIgZ1aLRNbwMMQCOAV0oBPABQAHZmw5cAImFYQAXHkQkYTMGoDk6CNgC0VLmVa7EAXwCUa%20nDQtWYADyM4zuSQDKZGGRCrAB8ANx8VsCRmgBuRMgBaHAAdNKespzcycJi4viEmtpqAEQGxqbkrMVRNuHAYAAekklk6pFAA)

```
declare global {
  interface Permissions {
    query(permissionDesc: { name: 'local-fonts' }): Promise<PermissionStatus>;
  }
}
navigator.permissions.query({
  name: "local-fonts"
});

export { }
```

Comment: Ah that's very clever! I guess this is a good solution in this case although sometimes many APIs may use the same time then we have to augment that many APIs.